# Function with await being executed before the awaited function

Tags: async-await, es6-promise

I need to create a chart based on the GET request.

For this I have 3 functions which should be executed in the following order:

1 - EventListener to trigger the function that draws the charts.

2 - The function that requests the object to draw the chart.

3 - The function that draws the chart.

For some reason I can't understand, the function that draws the chart seems to be ready before the GET request.

I have tried giving Async/Await to both the function that draws the charts and the function that request the object. But Iam doing something wrong :

```
searchForm.addEventListener("submit" , function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault(); // Evita a submissão normal do formulário  
        changeLogoImage(searchBar.value);
        giveCompanieSymbol(searchBar.value);
        turnDisplayBlock(mainContainer);
        console.log('This should come first')
        displayChart();
    }
)


async function displayChart()
    {   
        await objectForChart();
        console.log('This should come last');
        let ano = arrayOfMonths.slice(0,10)
        var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        (...)
     }

async function objectForChart()
{
    let http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    http.open('GET' , 'url');
    http.send();

    http.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if (http.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) 
        {
            let responseObject = JSON.parse(http.response);

            for(let month in responseObject['Monthly Time Series'] )
            {
                arrayOfMonths.push(month);
            }
            console.log('This should come 2nd');
        }
    }
}
```

The console gives me the logs in the following order :

-This should come first

-This should come last

-This should come second

Answer (score 2):

you need to await the request in `objectForChart`. try using fetch (promise based) instead of XMLHttpRequest (callback based).

```js
async function objectForChart() {
  const data = await fetch(url);
  return data.json();
}
```